# Regular expression

Tags: bash, scripts, sed, regex

I have a code that is looking for a specific pattern in my log files. Usually it begins with Association ID = (This is what I am looking for in parenthesis). Now the code I have made so far is throwing a syntax:

```
echo "Please enter the UID: ";
read uid

uidAssoc(){
        arg1=$1
        echo $arg1
        for arg1 in $(cat ~/jlog/server.log); do echo $word;done
        | sed 's/.AssociationID = \([*])\'
}
uidAssoc $uid
```

Can anyone throw suggestions as to how to correct the sed command and have it echo out the results found using it?

I have tried utilizing grep instead:

```
echo "Please enter the UID: ";
read uid

#Will parse through server log files for associaton
uidAssoc(){
        arg1=$1
        echo $arg1
        for arg1 in $(cat ~/jlog/server.log); do echo $word; done|
        grep Association ID ~/jlog/server.log |
        grep -E -o "[a-z0-9]" ~/jlog/server.log
}
uidAssoc $uid
exit
```

Here is my input:

```
    Please enter the UID:
1.2.124.113532.80.22187.2757.20140503.123509.1190654364
```

And for output:

```
l
e
o
p
i
c
g
e
n
t
e
a
n
r
o
c
e
s
s
e
d
i
n
s
t
a
n
c
e
1
2
1
2
4
1
1
3
5
3
2
8
0
2
2
1
8
7
2
7
```

Comment: Is the ID strictly alphanumeric? If so you could do `\(\w*\)` at the end. Also, it seems that your final `)\ ` may indeed want to be `\)`

Comment: it is alphanumeric

Comment: I did that but this is what I got for a response: `sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated s' command`. And furthermore the script freezes after that, even after I put `exit;` inside and outside the function

Comment: sed syntax for find and replace string is sed 's/regexp/replacement/' if you want to replace all occurrences sed 's/regexp/replacement/g'

Comment: What is your script actually supposed to do? at the moment it seems like a random collection of cats, pipes and variables which have no particular relation to one another.

Comment: I wonder what's the point of `arg1=$1` when it's immediately over-written in the for loop. What is `$word` supposed to be? Unless I am missing something, it isn't set.

Comment: arg1=$1 takes in the argument of what is written in SUID. From there I am trying to parse through a log file and find an association ID imbedded in the log file. To find the association ID i am attempting to use regex to find this: Association ID = (idiswritteninhereanditsalphanumeric)

Comment: @rye please improve the title of your question -- it very poorly describes your question and researchers with a similar probablem are virtual guaranteed to not find this page in search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a bulk of this at home. I have the code snippet below and i just gotta tweak around with it to figure out the rest of it:

```
echo "Please enter the UID: ";
read uid

#Will parse through server log files for associaton
uidAssoc(){
        arg1=$1
        echo $arg1
        for arg1 in $(cat ~/jlog/server.log); do echo $word;done |
        awk 'match($i, /Association ID = /){ print substr($i, RSTART,RLENGTH) 
        }
        ' ~/jlog/server.log
}
uidAssoc $uid
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in your sed segment.  Your output is sendin newline at the end of each character.

Replace sed (after | ):

sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' 's/.AssociationID = ([*])\'

This will read the whole file in a loop, then replaces the newline(s) with a space.

Update: explanation.

```
create a label via :a
append the current and next line to the pattern space via N
if we are before the last line, branch to the created label $!ba 
($! means not to do it on the last line (as there should be one final newline)).
finally the substitution replaces every newline with a space on the pattern space
(which is the whole file).
```

You may need to tweak this for your final output but, this should cure the one character per line problem with sed.